# Getting error number -1700 when trying to mount a network drive

Tags: mount, applescript, home-server, afp

I don't use AppleScript often but I wrote a short script to mount a network drive based on whether I am home or away:

```
set SSID to do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I | awk '/ SSID: / {print $2}'"

if SSID is "MyHomeSSID" then 
    mount volume "afp://my_local_home_server_address.local"
else if mount volume "afp://address_to_my_home_server:port" then

end if
```

When I run this, it displays a window allowing me to select the volume I want to mount, but then gives me the following error:

`error "Can’t make file \"Drive:\" into type boolean." number -1700 from file "Drive:" to boolean`

I can't figure out how to make this work without the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error you're getting:

> `error "Can’t make file \"Drive:\" into type boolean." number -1700 from file "Drive:" to boolean`

This is the culprit:

```
    else if mount volume "afp://address_to_my_home_server:port" then
```

Can you see why ? *[ Hint: `boolean` values are `true` and `false` ]*

You need to restructure the last half of your `if...then...else` control statement like so:

```
    if SSID is "MyHomeSSID" then 
        mount volume "afp://my_local_home_server_address.local"
    else 
        mount volume "afp://address_to_my_home_server:port"
    end if
```

Comment: Works now. I just took out "if" and it works great.